# self.string not retaining causing memory leaks iphone

Tags: iphone, nsstring, date, retain

I have a few dates and strings that are declared as nonatomic and retained.

When I set the date or change the string using `self.string` it isn't being retained. If I force it by `[string retain]` I have no issues, although this creates memory leaks.

Any ideas or how or what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Update:

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain)NSDate *time;
    self.time = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
```

`self.time` doesn't retain. I have to `[time retain];`

Comment: You will need to show some code examples of what you are trying.

Comment: You need to provide sample code, chances are if you are using the property correctly it is being over released else where.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't retain? Actually, it does if declared correctly. You need to show more code.

Comment: Where are you accessing self.time? Post that section of code. Also as someone else suggested, are you @synthesize 'ing your property and do you have an instance variable delcared for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either releasing the string twice or accessing it after it has already been released. If you post some code, it will help determine what's going on if that's not enough to go by.

Comment: Then you'll have to post up some code. Also what is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Just releasing (or over-releasing, or failing to retain) the string object wouldn't cause the property value to suddenly become null.  Something in your code somewhere is assigning a nil value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence:

```
0 NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
1 [obj retain]
2 [obj release]
3 [obj release]
4 NSLog("@%@",obj);
5 [obj retain]
```

will crash at line 4 (obj has been deallocated), while the sequence:

```
0 NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
1 [obj retain]
2 [obj retain]
3 [obj release]
4 [obj release]
4 NSLog("@%@",obj);
```

will leak (obj retain count is 1).

As you can see the same operations but in different order can change your object from being extra-deallocated to leaked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you synthesized the setters and getter methods?  They are synthesized by including the following line of code in the .m file:

```
@synthesize time;
```

Generally, you would do this right after the line:

```
@implementation YourClass
```

That's what actually generates the method that retains the variable when you set it, as you do, in:

```
self.time = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Comment: You should know that an object with the prefix of 'self' is a property of a viewController and therefore synthesized

Comment: That's not correct.  Properties only allow you to use dot notation (e.g. `self.time`), but do not synthesize setters and getters.  If you want to synthesize them, you have to do that explicitly. Then, they will be generated according to the rules of the property (e.g. retain). Moreover, properties can be used with any object, not only view controllers.

Comment: the viewController was an example.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to learn right now is how to find the cause of these kind of problems using Instruments.

In Xcode 4 go to Product / Profile, your project will compiled and Instruments window will appear. Choose the Allocations instrument, then stop automatically started execution by clicking on the red button that looks like a REC button.

Click on the little i button in front of Allocations instrument. And select "Record Reference Count" and "Enable NSZombie Detection", now run again by clicking that same red button. Reproduce the problem, when it crashs go back to the Instruments window and you will see a dialog box click on the arrow and search for the problem's origin. IMO you should look where your object is been wrongly released.

[image]